# Does using html 5 animation effects requires that much javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/webgl/html5-canvas-webgl-plane-with-three-js/

In this example its just a rotating plane.

I'm an html 5 beginner :)

However, look at how many calculation does the JS code.

I dont have any trouble with it.

but this is how its gonna be ? ( while learning html5)

for every animation I should **look for the js code ?** ( and try to custom it to my needs) ??

and if so , is there any centrelized place of general scripts for html 5 animations ?

Comment: If you think that's a lot of code, stop now and give up. That's not a lot of code.

Comment: @rob Im not afraid of code I just asked if i should know all these angles calculation etc....

Comment: That is the nature of 3D programming, manipulation, and scenery.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You should understand what your code is doing at all times if possible (i.e., you may at some point use a math library to solve a problem that is over your head, but you should still understand the model.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

Using canvas and JS, probably. The code is just a raw drawing board, so it is subject to the same drawing code you would using in most similar scenarios. three.js (as used in that example) is used to make things easier, and having a [3d drawing context](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Canvas:3D) for canvas will help, but it will be pretty much the same thing as three.js (it may be even using it, I don't know. Haven't used it before).

However, that said, for simple things like that, [CSS 3 3D animations](http://www.marcofolio.net/css/3d_animation_using_pure_css3.html) will make things possible. You can modify things like perspective and rotation and get effects like that. So it depends on what you will be using it for.

If you can get away with CSS and elements, than it can be pretty easy (keyframes and CSS styles). But if you're looking for more complicated 3d effects, than yes, it will be more complicated.

Comment: for the same effect with JS vs CSS , should i choose css ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It will depend. JS engines are likely going to be faster, so if you are doing a lot, or are doing complicated things, then WebGL and JS is the way to go. If you're going for simple effects, CSS could very well be worth it. Also, canvas compatibility is higher than CSS 3 (though not by much for WebGL accelerated effects).